# php null value returned from min() function

Tags: php

Why does

> var_dump(min(-100, -10, NULL, 10, 100));

return

> NULL

Any references to PHP documentation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PHP documentation on [Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), comparing `NULL` to anything results in both arguments being converted to bools, with `NULL` converting to `false`.

Since for numbers, [only 0 or 0.0 convert to false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), all of the other arguments passed to min are considered greater than NULL.

Comment: +1 - Was about to write the same, but Powerlord did a better job than me. Here's a script confirming this: https://eval.in/93446

Comment: But 0 is not less than any negatively signed number.

Comment: @robertrocha Which makes me wonder how it would sort things if you threw 0 in that list, too.